# Using Kohana Remote::get throws exception on http 500, but I need the response text

Tags: php, http, kohana, kohana-3

I'm making a `Remote::get` request to an API which answers with `http 500` when something goes wrong. The thing is that it also gives `{errorCode: x}` as a more detailed description of what went wrong in the response text. On some of the error codes I need to take different actions.

My problem is that Kohana throws an exception on `http 500` responses and thus bakes in my easy parsable response text in a "wordy" error message in the exception object.

Is there some way to get the response text of the `Remote::get` on a `http 500` response without having to parse a lengthy error description?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. Take a look at [source code](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.0/master/classes/kohana/remote.php#L85)

```
if ($code AND $code < 200 OR $code > 299)
{
    $error = $response;
}

...

if (isset($error))
{
    throw new Kohana_Exception('Error fetching remote :url [ status :code ] :error',
            array(':url' => $url, ':code' => $code, ':error' => $error));
}
```

[Kohana_Exception](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.0/master/classes/kohana/exception.php) doesn't help much

```
public function __construct($message, array $variables = NULL, $code = 0)
{
    // Set the message
    $message = __($message, $variables);

    // Pass the message to the parent
    parent::__construct($message, $code);
}
```

So it mixes all things into one message.

How about using different HTTP client? For example [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) - it is easier to [retrieve the body on error](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/467).